# Radio button not showing correctly in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button, android-jetpack-compose

I created a component selectableListItem() that has a title, subtitle, and radio button icon but it shows differently on different android devices. On the emulator, it shows fine...on a real device, no radio button is showing on second item and the first item radio button is small. On another real device... the radio button on second item is very small while others are fine.

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjYJZ.png) [another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df68O.png)

```
Column {
    FiveVerticalSpacer()
    valuePoll.forEachIndexed { index, saveCustomerRequest ->
        SelectionListItem(
            index = index,
            isSelected = saveCustomerRequest.title == onItemSelected.title,
            title = saveCustomerRequest.title,
            subTitle = saveCustomerRequest.description,
            onClick = {
                onItemSelected = saveCustomerRequest(
                    saveCustomerRequest.title,
                    saveCustomerRequest.description
                )
            }
        )
```

Comment: Can you share code for **SelectionListItem**

Comment: @sarthakgupta I have fixed it by setting width to the title and subtitle to make it wrapped.